# spring3 internationalization not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am newbie to spring.I used spring internationalization in my project.Below is my configuration

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/properties/messages" />
         <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
   </bean>


<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the properties folder i have three files.
**messages.properties**

```
label.username=user
```

**messages_en.properties**

```
label.username=hddhd
```

**messages_es.properties**

```
label.username=lalal
```

i display the message using     `<spring:message code="label.username" />` this tag.

But this one always prints the value from messages.properties.
It always  prints user.

even i give the url like below

```
[http://localhost:8080/Project/?lang=en
http://localhost:8080/Project/?lang=es][1]
```

why values not taken from the files messages_en and messages_es

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Do you have all 3 files in this path `WEB-INF/properties/messages` ?

Comment: yes,All those three files present in the same path

Comment: Have you checked in the console ? Any errors ?

Comment: yes,no error and  nothing is printed on console

Comment: i guess everything seems to be fine except `messages.properties` . so try removing `messages.properties` from the path as it doesnt correspond to any locale

Comment: now values get from  from messages_en.properties.but http://localhost:8080/Project/?lang=es this url gives the same result as http://localhost:8080/Project/?lang=en

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68204/discussion-between-madhesh-and-san-krish).

Comment: Do you use `<mvc:annotation-driven />`? If yes your `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` is basically not doing anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum,yes i use mvc:annotation-driven.I removed handler mapping and use mvc:interceptor now internationalization worked.please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` configuring the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` will not work. You should use the `<mvc:interceptors />` element to register the interceptors.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Next to that it doesn't work in newer versions of Spring (everything after 2.5) doesn't use the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` anymore in case of `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add this line

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```